# Why can't I import cplex?

Tags: python, import, package, jupyter, cplex

In my python jupyter notebook, I write the line "import cplex." I downloaded cplex off of the IBM website, but after running that line of code, I still get "No module named 'cplex'." Does anyone have any suggestions as to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
pip install cplex
```

in your venv kernel..

Comment: When I try that, I get this new error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cplex (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cplex
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: try upgrade pip or specifying the cplex version